# Constrained optimization with several equality constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

In maximizing a function of $n$ variables with $m$ equality constraints, it is required that the Jacobian derivative of constraints has full rank at optimal points. Can some one provide me with the geometric intuition behind this?

Comment: " it is required that the Jacobian derivative of constraints has full rank at optimal points. " Required by what? Why can't you still maximize the function if the constraints' Jacobian does not have full rank? In the full-rank case, you have freedom to move in $n-m$ directions. In the other case, some constraints are locally redundant and so, you have more flexibility, you can move in $n-r$ directions where $r$ is the rank.

Comment: Hi. I get your point. Can you also explain, why in the full rank case constraint set has a well defined n-m dimensional tangent plane everywhere? And for your first question, it is required by Non-degenerate constraint qualification

Comment: Without loss of generality we can write the constraints as $g(x)=0$. If $h$ is a tangent vector for this surface (i.e. an infinitesimal move along $h$ leave you in the constraint set) we have $0=g(x+h\cdot\epsilon)-g(x) \approx \nabla g(x)\cdot h$. That is $h$ must in the kernel of $\nabla g(x)$. So if the rank of $\nabla g$ is $r$ then then dimension of the kernel is the dimension of the total space $n$ minus the dimension of the image $r$. Not sure if this is what you asked but I did not fully understand the question.

Comment: Thank you. That was a simple and clear explanation.